# Selecting the row cells in an code using userform

Tags: excel, vba

We are getting "Object Required Error" while running below code.

Could you please advise what would be the mistake.

```
Private Sub cmdCosmetic_Click()
    lstloadcos.RowSource = ""
    lstloadcos.RowSource = "Sheet1!B3:B" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there a `Sheet1` sheet, named "Sheet1"?

Comment: Yes. The sheet hasn't renamed. So its Sheet1